# Is it possible to use multiple layers of inherited @MockBean?

Tags: java, spring, mocking

I am trying to organize our usage of @MockBean to reduce the number of ApplicationContexts in use during our testing. My approach is to put shared
mocks in super classes and then inherit into the actual test code.

I have a hierarchy like this:

BaseTest:

```
@ActiveProfiles({"test", "human-readable-logging"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Main.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location="})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(print = MockMvcPrint.NONE)
public class BaseTest {}
```

BaseUnitTestMocks: this has two subclasses

```
public class BaseUnitTestMocks extends BaseTest {
  @MockBean private ServiceA serviceA;
  @MockBean private ServiceB serviceB;

   ... accessors ...
```

BaseUnitTest: this is on the inheritance line with the problem.

```
@Tag("unit")
@ActiveProfiles("unit-test")
public class BaseUnitTest extends BaseUnitTestMocks {}
```

BaseUnitTestPlusOneMock: this mock seems to not make it into the application context

```
public class BaseUnitTestPlusOneMock extends BaseUnitTest {
  @MockBean private ServiceC serviceC;
   ... accessor ...
}
```

The test class looks like this:

```
public class MyTest extends BaseUnitTestPlusOneMock {
  private static final FAKE_THING = "fake_thing";

  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() throws IOException {
    when(mockServiceC().getRequiredThing(any())).thenReturn(FAKE_THING);
  }

    ... tests ...
```

**Expected Result:**
The mock is included in the application context and used in the Autowired in ServiceC.

**Actual Result:**
This works when run from the debugger in IntelliJ. When run in a clean environment (cleaned project and stopped all gradle daemons), not in the debugger it fails because the actual ServiceC is used.

Comment: After more experimentation, I believe the problem is that when this test is run, the Spring system does not realize it needs a new application context. So the test code is using a mock, but the service code is still using a real class. Adding a class-level @DirtiesContext BEFORE_CLASS gets me a new application context and things work.